# String Manipulation from "[1_5],[1_3],[1_5]" to "5,3,5"

Tags: vb.net

I have the a string in below format

```
Dim str as String = "[1_5],[1_3],[1_5]"
```

The part before the _ can be variable is not a fix number 
i need to convert it in to format

```
"5,3,5"
```

i have used the below code to obtain all the number that i need in the new string in the matches Item Groups

```
Dim pattern As String = "_(.*?)\]"
Dim matches As MatchCollection = 
Regex.Matches(rowpanel.getRequestedArea_selectionArea(), pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

My question is how i can join all the Groups to obtain the final string format ?

Comment: Do you really need a regex solution or you can accept also a Split and Join one?

Comment: `dim result = string.Join(",", Regex.Matches(inputString, "\[\d+_(\d+)\]").OfType(Of Match)().Select(Function(m) m.Groups(1)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Regex solution could be

```
Dim x = matches.Select(Function(g) g.Groups(1).Value)
Dim final = String.Join(",", x)
```

A Split and Join one is

```
Dim blocks As String() = str.Split(",")
Dim result = New List(Of String)()

For Each s In blocks

    result.Add(s.Split("_")(1).Trim("]"))
Next
Dim final = String.Join(",", result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using RegEx and replace:

```
Dim str As String = "[1_5],[1_3],[1_5]"
Dim RegX As Regex = New Regex("\[\d{1}_")
Dim match As Match = RegX.Match(str)


If match.Success Then
    str = Replace(str, match.Value, "")
    str = Replace(str, "]", "")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative with simple and readable loop but multiple lines of code wrapped with a method

```
Public Function ExtractNumbers(text As String) As String
    Dim current As New StringBuilder()
    Dim write As Boolean = False

    For Each character As Char In text
        If character = "_"c Then
            write = True
            Continue For
        End If

        If character = "]"c Then
            write = False
            current.Append(",")
            Continue For
        End If

        If write Then
            current.Append(character)
            Continue For
        End If
    Next

    current.Length -= 1
    Return current.ToString()
End Function
```

Usage

```
var extracted = ExtractNumbers("[1_5],[1_3],[1_5]")

Console.WriteLine(extracted)
' 5,3,5
```